# Cant install Provus via Docksal

Tags: installation

I have a problem running Provus on local env via Docksal. [Provus](https://github.com/promet/provus)

```
> git clone https://github.com/promet/provus.git ppd9
> cd ppd9
> fin init
```

Errors via installations

```
[error]  Drupal\Core\File\Exception\NotRegularDirectoryException: public://geofieldmap_icons is not a directory. in Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem->scanDirectory() (line 665 of /var/www/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileSystem.php).
```

second

```
[error]  Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigException: Errors occurred during import in Drush\Drupal\Commands\config\ConfigImportCommands->doImport() (line 346 of /var/www/vendor/drush/drush/src/Drupal/Commands/config/ConfigImportCommands.php). 

In ConfigImportCommands.php line 360:
                                                                                                                                                                                   
  The import failed due to the following reasons:                                                                                                                                  
  Unexpected error during import with operation delete for taxonomy.vocabulary.tags: Attempt to create a field body that does not exist on entity type block_content.              
  Unexpected error during import with operation delete for contact.form.personal: Attempt to create a field body that does not exist on entity type block_content.                 
  Unexpected error during import with operation delete for contact.form.feedback: Attempt to create a field body that does not exist on entity type block_content.                 
  Unexpected error during import with operation delete for field.field.block_content.basic.body: Attempt to create a field body that does not exist on entity type block_content.  
  Unexpected error during import with operation delete for field.field.node.article.body: Attempt to create a field body that does not exist on entity type node.                  
  Unexpected error during import with operation delete for field.field.node.page.body: Attempt to create a field body that does not exist on entity type node.                     
  Unexpected error during import with operation delete for node.type.page: Attempt to create a field body that does not exist on entity type block_content.                        
  Unexpected error during import with operation delete for node.type.article: Attempt to create a field body that does not exist on entity type block_content.                     
  Unexpected error during import with operation delete for block_content.type.basic: Attempt to create a field body that does not exist on entity type block_content.
```

third errors and warning

```
 [warning] Components 8.x-1.x API is deprecated in components:8.x-2.0 and is removed from components:3.0.0. Update the provus.info.yml file to replace the component-libraries.[namespace].paths data with components.namespaces.[namespace]. See https://www.drupal.org/node/3082817
 [error]  Drupal\Core\File\Exception\NotRegularDirectoryException: public://geofieldmap_icons is not a directory. in Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem->scanDirectory() (line 665 of /var/www/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileSystem.php).
```

Anybody have suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: My suggestion is to ask in the issue queue for that project, as this problem seems to be with that project and not with Drupal.

Comment: Thanks, I already did, will share answers if solution came up!

Comment: Did you at least consider executing `mkdir sites/default/files/geofieldmap_icons`?

Comment: thanks, but still got errors, this `[warning] Use of undefined constant CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY - assumed 'CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) settings.promet.php:16` and second still remains

Comment: `settings.promet.php` is part of that special distribution but the message in your comment above is only a warning, not an error.